# Problem mounting a large shared folder

Tags: mount, 22.04, samba, cifs, shared-folders

I have a NAS and one Ubuntu on a VPS.I use Tailscale to make the connection between my NAS and the VPS, link is OK using this command :

```
sudo mount -o user=USER,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //100.95.78.23/Plex\ Media\ Server /NAS
```

The command "ls /NAS" is way too long just to show me the content on it while all was okay a day ago, idk why I didn't touched anything, maybe it's because the folder is way too big (70TB) ?

Using Ubuntu Jammy 22.04, all updates done.

Comment: *"maybe it's because the folder is way too big (70TB)"*... It's not the size but rather the number of files and directories under the mount point ... `ls` sorts the output by default ... Test without sorting `ls -1U` or with `find` instead to compare.

Comment: I use now this command and it's like 2/3x faster than the previous one :

sshfs USER@100.95.78.23:/share/ZFS19_DATA/Plex\ Media\ Server /NAS -o allow_other

idk why the previous one is too slow now and I really have a lot of files and folder but why is it now faster with sshfs